# Java Transparency rendering error

Tags: java, swing, transparency, repaint, paintcomponent

I am currently developing a kiosk style Java program to display weather, time, forecast etc. Here is a shot of what the program *should* look like (screenshot taken before the time updated)

[image: Image showing required output before the graphical error]

The various sections are created as JPanels with the `paintComponent()` method overridden. They draw in a gradient header and a semitransparent background. However, when I change the content of one of these panels, the previous content is left behind, rather than being removed. An example is shown below:

As you can see, when the time changed from 11:51 to 11:52, the numbers overlapped, and the background became lighter (because the semitransparent background was redrawn over it)

### The Graphical Error

[image: Image showing the graphical error]

What should I do to prevent this overlap? Ultimately, I would prefer to not have to redraw the entire screen when an individual panel updates it's contents. I would prefer to only redraw that particular section. It would be easy to repaint the background, and then all the components within.

## Update

Several answers involve clearing the area to be drawn. Whether I use `g.clear()` or `AlphaComposite.CLEAR` it erases the background image. this can be seen in the following image. Perhaps if I could copy the background before I clear the area, I could repaint that section of the background, then layer the other images appropriately. Thoughts?

[image]

## Update 2

An answer was submitted which shows a complete working example of a timer laid over a transparent panel and a background. This is very useful, however, I am not painting my sub-componenets manually. The time, weather icons and temperatures are all JLabels laid out over the semi-transparent panel. I would prefer to not have to paint the individual components manually.

Comment: Ah, I am overriding `paintComponent()` but mistyped. I will edit the question to reflect this

Comment: I've edited the question to further explain my problem.

Comment: Are the components set to transparent? `setOpaque(false)` it's hard to tell with out a code sample

Comment: Just like to say, it's looks really nice ;)

Comment: Yes. I call setOpaque() on all the necessary components

Answer (score 4):

A similar problem

[image: image before]

is addressed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2163544/re-paint-on-translucent-frame-panel-component/2166500#2166500)

[image: image after]

Note also, "Swing programs should override `paintComponent()` instead of overriding `paint()`."—[*Painting in AWT and Swing: The Paint Methods*](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index.html#callbacks).

Comment: Why "here" contains the link to the image shown below ? Or is it suppose to contain the link to your answer ?

Comment: You're MOST WELCOME and KEEP SMILING :-)

Comment: That is very helpful, but the problem persists if I try to clear an area. It then erases the picture which is showing through, and the text is then drawn on the background of the root pane.

Comment: If you can't use Java 7 or your platform precludes a transparent top-level container, you might try a [full screen window](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7457102/230513) and render the background on a panel added to the root pane.

Answer (score 3):

Before you do your paint, make a [g.clearRect(0,0,w,h)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#clearRect%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) call.
This will remove everything in the specified area, and you won't be drawing on top of the previous frame.

You may want to apply some double buffering techniques since your screen will flash slightly due to the clear.

Comment: I've tried that, but it fills in the background with the default grey background. How could it to truely clear the pixels?

Also, wouldnt that erase the background as well?

Comment: The documentation says it `Clears the specified rectangle by filling it with the background color of the current drawing surface.` It doesn't actually clear the graphics context.

Comment: You will need to set the background color of your panel, since that's what it sets the colors to. panel.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));

Comment: clearRect may "fill" the background, but it doesn't it differently from fillRect. It replaces the existing value of each pixel rather than adding to it.

Comment: Found this question too, which may be useful to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367365/clear-a-transparent-bufferedimage-as-fast-as-possible

Comment: Thank you for your help. I've tried several methods to remove the already painted image, but it also removes the background image which is meant to show through. I've updated the question to reflect this

Comment: If you are doing the whole window as one image, you will have to repaint it all, including the background. If you use several buffer images, or layered components, then you can redraw easily. If you use buffered images, keep the background as one static image, and then when you redraw, draw that buffer (which is a fast operation) and then the window contents.

Answer (score 3):

I put this together really quickly it's nothing special...

[image]

The entire project consists of a JFrame, a BackgroundImagePane and the ClockPane

The ClockPane looks like this (as you can recreate the rest ;))

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.geom.RoundRectangle2D;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class ClockPane extends javax.swing.JPanel {

    private Timer tick;

    protected static final SimpleDateFormat SDF = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm.ss");

    public ClockPane() {

        setOpaque(false);

        tick = new Timer(500, new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

                repaint();

            }

        });

        tick.setCoalesce(true);
        tick.setRepeats(true);

        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
        setMinimumSize(new Dimension(100, 100));

    }

    @Override
    public void addNotify() {

        super.addNotify();

        tick.start();

    }

    @Override
    public void removeNotify() {

        tick.stop();

        super.removeNotify();

    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics grphcs) {

        super.paintComponent(grphcs);

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) grphcs;

        int width = getWidth() - 1;
        int height = getHeight() - 1;

        Color background = new Color(192, 192, 192, 128);
        Color border = new Color(128, 128, 128);
        RoundRectangle2D backing = new RoundRectangle2D.Float(0, 0, width, height, 20, 20);

        g2d.setPaint(background);
        g2d.fill(backing);
        g2d.setPaint(border);
        g2d.draw(backing);

        String text = SDF.format(new Date());
        FontMetrics fm = g2d.getFontMetrics();
        g2d.setPaint(Color.BLACK);

        int x = (width - fm.stringWidth(text)) / 2;
        int y = ((height - fm.getHeight()) / 2) + fm.getAscent();

        g2d.drawString(text, x, y);

    }

}
```

With this, the clock updates every half second or so and I have no issues with the repaint

The only thing of significance I can think of is `setOpaque(false);`

**UPDATED**

This example is completly done with nothing but labels and panels (the background pane is a custom paint job and the date label has its background painted as well, but otherwise)

[image: Normal Components]

Now, I hacked my together, so it's not as nice as yours, but then again, I'm not getting paid ;)

```
import core.ui.UIUtilities;
import core.ui.WindowUtilities;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

public class MainFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form MainFrame
     */
    public MainFrame() {

        setUndecorated(true);
        WindowUtilities.setOpaque(this, false);

        initComponents();

        Timer timer = new Timer(500, new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                lblTime.setText(new SimpleDateFormat("hh:MM:ss").format(new Date()));

            }
        });

        timer.setRepeats(true);
        timer.setCoalesce(true);
        timer.start();

        DateLabel label = new DateLabel();
        label.init();

        NewBackgroundPane backgroundPane = new NewBackgroundPane();
        backgroundPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        backgroundPane.add(label, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        backgroundPane.add(pnlMain);

        add(backgroundPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        pack();

        setLocation(UIUtilities.centerOfDefaultScreen(this));

    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
    private void initComponents() {
        java.awt.GridBagConstraints gridBagConstraints;

        pnlMain = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        lblTime = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        lblExtTime = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jPanel3 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel6 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jPanel4 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jPanel5 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel11 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel12 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel13 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel14 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jPanel6 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel15 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel16 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel17 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel18 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jPanel7 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel19 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel20 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel21 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel22 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        pnlMain.setOpaque(false);
        pnlMain.setLayout(new java.awt.GridBagLayout());

        jPanel2.setOpaque(false);
        jPanel2.setLayout(new java.awt.GridBagLayout());

        lblTime.setFont(lblTime.getFont().deriveFont(lblTime.getFont().getStyle() | java.awt.Font.BOLD, lblTime.getFont().getSize()+18));
        lblTime.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        lblTime.setText("jLabel1");
        gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 0;
        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 1;
        jPanel2.add(lblTime, gridBagConstraints);

        lblExtTime.setFont(lblExtTime.getFont().deriveFont(lblExtTime.getFont().getSize()+6f));
        lblExtTime.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        lblExtTime.setText("AM EDT");
        gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 1;
        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 1;
        gridBagConstraints.anchor = java.awt.GridBagConstraints.PAGE_START;
        jPanel2.add(lblExtTime, gridBagConstraints);

        gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 0;
        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 1;
        gridBagConstraints.fill = java.awt.GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gridBagConstraints.weightx = 1.0;
        gridBagConstraints.insets = new java.awt.Insets(2, 2, 2, 2);
        pnlMain.add(jPanel2, gridBagConstraints);

        jPanel3.setOpaque(false);
        jPanel3.setLayout(new java.awt.GridBagLayout());

        jLabel3.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/transparentUpdate/Overcast.png"))); // NOI18N
        gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 0;
        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 0;
        gridBagConstraints.gridheight = 2;
        jPanel3.add(jLabel3, gridBagConstraints);

        jLabel4.setFont(jLabel4.getFont().deriveFont(jLabel4.getFont().getSize()+6f));
        jLabel4.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jLabel4.setText("<html>Currenctly<br>Overast</html>");
        gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 1;
        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 0;
        gridBagConstraints.gridwidth = 2;
        gridBagConstraints.anchor = java.awt.GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
        jPanel3.add(jLabel4, gridBagConstraints);

        jLabel5.setFont(jLabel5.getFont().deriveFont(jLabel5.getFont().getSize()+12f));
        jLabel5.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jLabel5.setText("69");
        gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 1;
        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 1;
        gridBagConstraints.anchor = java.awt.GridBagConstraints.LAST_LINE_START;
        jPanel3.add(jLabel5, gridBagConstraints);

        jLabel6.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jLabel6.setText("/65");
        gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 2;
        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 1;
        gridBagConstraints.anchor = java.awt.GridBagConstraints.LAST_LINE_START;
        jPanel3.add(jLabel6, gridBagConstraints);

        gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 0;
        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 2;
        gridBagConstraints.fill = java.awt.GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gridBagConstraints.weightx = 1.0;
        gridBagConstraints.insets = new java.awt.Insets(2, 2, 2, 2);
        pnlMain.add(jPanel3, gridBagConstraints);

        jPanel4.setOpaque(false);
        jPanel4.setLayout(new java.awt.GridBagLayout());

        jPanel5.setOpaque(false);
        jPanel5.setLayout(new java.awt.GridBagLayout());

        jLabel11.setFont(jLabel11.getFont().deriveFont(jLabel11.getFont().getSize()+4f));
        jLabel11.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jLabel11.setText("Today");
        gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 0;
        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 0;
        gridBagConstraints.gridwidth = 2;
        jPanel5.add(jLabel11, gridBagConstraints);

        jLabel12.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jLabel12.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/transparentUpdate/SmallOvercast.png"))); // NOI18N
        gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 0;
        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 1;
        gridBagConstraints.gridheight = 2;
        jPanel5.add(jLabel12, gridBagConstraints);

        jLabel13.setFont(jLabel13.getFont().deriveFont(jLabel13.getFont().getSize()+4f));
        jLabel13.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jLabel13.setText("83");
        gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 1;
        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 1;
        gridBagConstraints.anchor = java.awt.GridBagConstraints.PAGE_START;
        jPanel5.add(jLabel13, gridBagConstraints);

        jLabel14.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jLabel14.setText("65");
        gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 1;
        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 2;
        gridBagConstraints.anchor = java.awt.GridBagConstraints.PAGE_START;
        jPanel5.add(jLabel14, gridBagConstraints);

        gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 0;
        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 0;
        gridBagConstraints.anchor = java.awt.GridBagConstraints.PAGE_START;
        gridBagConstraints.insets = new java.awt.Insets(2, 4, 2, 4);
        jPanel4.add(jPanel5, gridBagConstraints);

        jPanel6.setOpaque(false);
        jPanel6.setLayout(new java.awt.GridBagLayout());

        jLabel15.setFont(jLabel15.getFont().deriveFont(jLabel15.getFont().getSize()+4f));
        jLabel15.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jLabel15.setText("Sunday");
        gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 0;
        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 0;
        gridBagConstraints.gridwidth = 2;
        jPanel6.add(jLabel15, gridBagConstraints);

        jLabel16.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jLabel16.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/transparentUpdate/Sunny.png"))); // NOI18N
        gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 0;
        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 1;
        gridBagConstraints.gridheight = 2;
        jPanel6.add(jLabel16, gridBagConstraints);

        jLabel17.setFont(jLabel17.getFont().deriveFont(jLabel17.getFont().getSize()+4f));
        jLabel17.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jLabel17.setText("82");
        gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 1;
        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 1;
        gridBagConstraints.anchor = java.awt.GridBagConstraints.PAGE_START;
        jPanel6.add(jLabel17, gridBagConstraints);

        jLabel18.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jLabel18.setText("64");
        gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 1;
        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 2;
        gridBagConstraints.anchor = java.awt.GridBagConstraints.PAGE_START;
        jPanel6.add(jLabel18, gridBagConstraints);

        gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 1;
        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 0;
        gridBagConstraints.anchor = java.awt.GridBagConstraints.PAGE_START;
        gridBagConstraints.insets = new java.awt.Insets(2, 4, 2, 4);
        jPanel4.add(jPanel6, gridBagConstraints);

        jPanel7.setOpaque(false);
        jPanel7.setLayout(new java.awt.GridBagLayout());

        jLabel19.setFont(jLabel19.getFont().deriveFont(jLabel19.getFont().getSize()+4f));
        jLabel19.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jLabel19.setText("Monday");
        gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 0;
        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 0;
        gridBagConstraints.gridwidth = 2;
        jPanel7.add(jLabel19, gridBagConstraints);

        jLabel20.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jLabel20.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/transparentUpdate/Cloudy.png"))); // NOI18N
        gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 0;
        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 1;
        gridBagConstraints.gridheight = 2;
        jPanel7.add(jLabel20, gridBagConstraints);

        jLabel21.setFont(jLabel21.getFont().deriveFont(jLabel21.getFont().getSize()+4f));
        jLabel21.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jLabel21.setText("83");
        gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 1;
        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 1;
        gridBagConstraints.anchor = java.awt.GridBagConstraints.PAGE_START;
        jPanel7.add(jLabel21, gridBagConstraints);

        jLabel22.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jLabel22.setText("84");
        gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 1;
        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 2;
        gridBagConstraints.anchor = java.awt.GridBagConstraints.PAGE_START;
        jPanel7.add(jLabel22, gridBagConstraints);

        gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 2;
        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 0;
        gridBagConstraints.anchor = java.awt.GridBagConstraints.PAGE_START;
        gridBagConstraints.insets = new java.awt.Insets(2, 4, 2, 4);
        jPanel4.add(jPanel7, gridBagConstraints);

        gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 0;
        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 3;
        gridBagConstraints.fill = java.awt.GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gridBagConstraints.weightx = 1.0;
        gridBagConstraints.insets = new java.awt.Insets(2, 2, 2, 2);
        pnlMain.add(jPanel4, gridBagConstraints);

        getContentPane().add(pnlMain, java.awt.BorderLayout.CENTER);

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /*
         * Set the Nimbus look and feel
         */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /*
         * If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the
         * default look and feel. For details see
         * http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html
         */
        try {

            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /*
         * Create and display the form
         */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                new MainFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel11;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel12;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel13;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel14;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel15;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel16;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel17;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel18;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel19;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel20;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel21;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel22;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel6;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel3;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel4;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel5;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel6;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel7;
    private javax.swing.JLabel lblExtTime;
    private javax.swing.JLabel lblTime;
    private javax.swing.JPanel pnlMain;
    // End of variables declaration
}
```

Just to make life eaiser, the background pane

```
import java.awt.AlphaComposite;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

public class NewBackgroundPane extends javax.swing.JPanel {

    /**
     * Creates new form NewBackgroundPane
     */
    public NewBackgroundPane() {
        initComponents();
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        super.paintComponent(g);

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();

        int width = getWidth() - 1;
        int height = getHeight() - 1;

        g2d.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, 0.5f));
        g2d.fillRoundRect(0, 0, width, height, 20, 20);
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
    private void initComponents() {

        setOpaque(false);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this);
        this.setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 300, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
    }// </editor-fold>
    // Variables declaration - do not modify
    // End of variables declaration
}
```

If you still can't get it to work, the only other issue I can think of could have to something to do with been in full screen, exclusive mode, I've not tested that :P

Comment: Thank you for this great example! The only problem is that I am not rendering the time myself. I have several JLabel components laid out carefully around the panel. It's when I update these that I get the issue

Comment: You shouldn't have to, the example is soly used to demonstrate that it's possible.  I'll see if I can update with labels for :)