# Fast way to clear background

Tags: java, java-2d

I am currently profiling my Java-2d-Application (Game-Engine for learning purposes).
Since I cannot guarantee that each frame is overwritten completely, I have to clear the background to a solid color (i.e. Color.BLACK) each frame.

The way I do it is SLOW (about 40% of drawing-time in my environment goes to just clearing the background).

First I get a graphics-context from the bufferStrategy, then I draw a [PickYourColor]-Rectangle in full resolution on it before drawing the actual content.

```
// fill background with solid color
graphics.setColor(Color.BLACK);
graphics.fillRect(
                0,
                0,
                (int) bounds.getWidth(),
                (int) bounds.getHeight());
```

Is there a more efficient, platform-independant, way to clear the background to a solid color each frame using Java-2D (this is not a LWJGL-question)?

What I'm looking for is a graphics.clearBackgroundToSolidColor(Color color) - Method...

By request: here the full rendering method (it's not an SSCCE, but it's pretty short and self explanatory)

```
/**
 * Create a new graphics context to draw on and
 * notify all RenderListeners about rendering.
 */
public void render() {

    ///// abort drawing if we don't have focus /////
    if (!this.windowJFrame.hasFocus()) {
        return;
    }


    ///// draw and create new graphics context /////
    Graphics2D graphics = null;
    do {

        try {
            graphics = (Graphics2D) this.bufferStrategy.getDrawGraphics();
            Rectangle2 bounds = this.getBounds();

            // set an inexpensive, yet pretty nice looking, rendering directives
            graphics.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION,
                    RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
            graphics.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                    RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);



            // fill background with solid color
            graphics.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            graphics.fillRect(
                    0,
                    0,
                    (int) bounds.getWidth(),
                    (int) bounds.getHeight());


            // notify all listeners that they can draw now
            synchronized (this.renderListeners) {
                for (RenderInterface r : this.renderListeners) {
                    r.render(graphics, bounds);
                }
            }

            // show buffer
            graphics.dispose();
            this.bufferStrategy.show();


        } catch (Exception e) {

            Logger.saveMessage("window", Logger.WARNING, "Caught exception while drawing frame. Exception: " + e.toString());
        }

    } while (this.bufferStrategy.contentsLost());

}
```

Comment: I use `fillRect` in all of my applications and I have never had performance issues with it.

Comment: Any improvement with `setBackground(Color)` and `clearRect(int,int,int,int)`?

Comment: Y are you so sure its the `fillRect` that is slow? can you post your full rendering method?

Comment: @RealSkeptic: that's depricated and I prefer not to use it (besides it has the exact same performance) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367365/clear-a-transparent-bufferedimage-as-fast-as-possible

Comment: @DimaMaligin: 100% sure, because if I comment out the above lines I get an approx. 40% performance boost. Of course in other environments or applications the percentage may be more or less (@TameHog: this might be the reason why you don't have issues with it), but on high resolution (Full-HD and above) the filling algorithm is slow (tested on 4 windows-pcs)

Comment: @Florian Well if you only fill the bg it seems right. I mean if you have 1080p of bg to fill and on top of it you only draw 1 small rectangle like 50x50 its soposed to take longer to fill the bg.

Comment: @DimaMaligin: i totally agree (though it's an extreme scenario), but if you draw on 99% of the screen you still have to clear the whole background to get that 1% (or have a very sophisticated masking algorithm which I am not able to develop ;-)) Bottom line I see only two possible solutions: 1: live with it / 2: make sure you draw something usefull on the whole scene so you don't have to clear the background.

Comment: Are y double buffering the output?

Comment: I'd like to see a real source for this "Deprecated" thing. It's not in the Javadoc, and there are enough ancient methods that are marked as deprecated (Thread.stop comes to mind). That being said, if there is no performance difference, forget it.

Comment: @Florian See my suggestion below, and BTW just how slow is slow?

Comment: @RealSkeptic using the bg color and `clearRect` is "tecnicaly" not deprecated but its strongly recommended to use `fillRect` instead. From the API docs **`Beginning with Java 1.1, the background color of offscreen images may be system dependent. Applications should use setColor followed by fillRect to ensure that an offscreen image is cleared to a specific color`**.

Comment: @MadProgrammer yes: first I get the buffer capabilities and - depending on the system - I double or tripple-buffer (but I tested it already without buffering at all and it is on my 4 systems not relevant to the performance)

Comment: @Dima Maligin a good point! "slow" is of course a relative term. I was just surprised about the "big" performance impact a fillRect has (especially on high resolution). I suspect it's happening in System-RAM not VRAM, that's why. But Java-internals are still mostly a secret to me... My expectation would have been, that it is implemented in a way that's MUCH faster than drawing an image of the same size (it's "only" about twice as fast in my non-representative tests)

Comment: @Florian whether its in RAM or VRAM depends on several things. For starters what `Component` are you drawing on? And please share your FPS.

Comment: @DimaMaligin Not sure that applies when using `Graphics2D` where the `setBackground()` method is defined. In `Graphics` it doesn't exist and so it may well be that you have no control over the background.

Comment: If you want to fill the entire screen try `canvas.drawColor(color, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR)`

Answer (score 0):

I can't say why the `fillRect` is slow, but you can try creating an `Image` and draw it as bg. not sure if it will be faster though.

try:

```
BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(500, 500, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
int[] imageData =((DataBufferInt)bi.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
Arrays.fill(imageData, 0);
```

then instead of `fillRect` draw the `Image`:

```
graphics.drawImage(bi, 0, 0, null);
```

Tell me how it went(I have my doubts about this).

Comment: so... what you are basically doing is overwriting the internal int[]-array of the graphics-context?

Comment: Just drawing an `Image` instead of `fillRect`

Comment: oh... ok ;-) in your code we would have to stretch the image to frame width and height while drawing (or transforming it beforehand). stretching is an expensive-operation, especially if you use interpolation bilinear or bicubic. so in your example the buffered image would have to be created with dimensionx of frame which I tested before posting this question. It's about half the speed of a fillRect. Maybe fillRect IS the most efficient way in Java2D *sigh*

Comment: @Florian I still don't know the FPS you are getting, I used `fillRect` on 1080p `Canvas` before and got around 900fps for the bg fill only.

Comment: sorry (pretty late here): approx. 190fps WITH fillRect, approx 240 without - this depends a lot on the system I am on (my netbook is considerable  slower ;-))

Comment: @Florian well 190 is not that slow. If rendering speed is your first priority maybe use openGL or something, there are plenty API's for that including the one you mentioned `LWJGL`, which I had used and recommend as its quite nice and easy.

Comment: yepp, but openGL (native) is WAY to complicated for me as I wan't to spend some time on the engine and not just the drawing-part but LWJGL is worth a closer look. Besides: 190 is not that bad I agree, but the most important thing is, that I am now pretty sure, I am doing it the most efficient way possible in Java2D - will have to do for now (I can still switch to another drawing-algorithm later if it is a concern)

Comment: @Florian If you do decide to go for openGL make sure to use openGL3+ and not the old ones with the crappy `GL.begin()` methods. Use VAO's instead of drawing from VertexArrays directly, and do take the time to write your own SLDL shaders they can speed things up a whole lot.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to clear the entire background than try `canvas.drawColor(color, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR)`. Should be a bit faster